# awk directory of files

Tags: awk

Given a directory full of .sam files, for each file:

1. if column3=blah and 451000 =< column4 <= 468999, write line to file_ribos.sam
2. otherwise, write line to file_non_ribos.sam

Example Input

```
# file_1.sam    
abc  123  blah  451200
abc  123  blah  450999
```

Example Output

```
# file_1_ribos.sam
abc  123  blah  451200

# file_1_non_ribos.sam
abc  123  blah  450999
```

My code seems to be failing. What am I doing wrong?

```
for file in *.sam ; do
  awk -F"\t" '
   {if($3 == "blah" && $4 >= "451000" && $4 <= "468999") {
     {print $0} > "$(basename "$file" .sam)_ribos.sam";}
    else {print $0} > "$(basename "$file" .sam)_non_ribos.sam";}
  ' $file;
done
```

Comment: Please edit some sample input into your question...

Comment: This is not a bioinformatics site, most people here will have no idea what .sam files are. Please include an example of the files you are parsing when asking questions. You also need to show us your desired output and explain exactly _how_ your "code is failing".

Comment: Extra { unclosed in your code. Just before first print. Note that @Janis solution should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've refactored your code a bit...

```
for file in *.sam ; do
  awk -v basename="$(basename $file .sam)" '
    { non = ($3 == "blah" && $4 >= 451000 && $4 <= 468999) ? "" : "_non"
      outfile = basename non "_ribos.sam"
      print > outfile
    }
  ' "$file"
done
```